# PrimeNg styleClass not change style of p-panel

Tags: css, angular, primeng

I am using primeNg. My .html and .scss file like below. But I can't give any styleClass to p-panel. What is wrong in my code?

.html file

```
<p-panel header="Student Info" styleClass="test">
    <div class="ui-g">
      <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-3">
        <div class="ui-g-12">
          <b>Student</b>
        </div>
       </div>
  </p-panel>
```

.scss file

```
.test {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To apply a CSS style to a child component, use `::ng-deep`. See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-p-checkbox-issue-ftbmep) for a demo.

```
:host ::ng-deep .test {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

According to [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep):

> Component styles normally apply only to the HTML in the component's
>   own template.
>
> Use the /deep/ shadow-piercing descendant combinator to force a style
>   down through the child component tree into all the child component
>   views. The /deep/ combinator works to any depth of nested components,
>   and it applies to both the view children and content children of the
>   component.
>
> Use /deep/, >>> and ::ng-deep only with emulated view encapsulation.
>   Emulated is the default and most commonly used view encapsulation.
>
> ...
>   ::ng-deep should be preferred for a broader compatibility with the
>   tools.

---

An alternative solution is to set the [view encapsulation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation) of the component to `ViewEncapsulation.None`.

Another alternative is to define the style globally in `styles.css`, as shown for the second panel in the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-p-checkbox-issue-ftbmep).

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. But why i must do? Should i do for every primeng component styling? @ConnorsFan

Comment: I added explanations taken from the Angular documentation, and alternative solutions.

Comment: @ConnorsFan Did you change stackblitz ? I don't see ng-deep part in provided link.

Answer (score 1):

One more solution is to use the parent element of `<p-panel>` element. So for,

```
<div class="panel-container">
   <p-panel>
     ..
   </p-panel>
 </div>
```

We could simply have a class as: 
`.panel-container div.ui-panel-titlebar {
 ..
}`


and/or

`.panel-container div.ui-panel-content {
 ..
}`
 

BTW to fix @HasanOzdemir's problem we could simply add a little padding to the top of parent element ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The way I've done this (to remove the bottom padding in the p-panel-content - in this case) is in the html add a new style class p-panel-no-padding-bottom to the styleClass of the p-panel I want to affect the style of..

```
<p-panel header="Panel Header" styleClass="p-panel-no-padding-bottom">
```

And either

1. in the global css

```css
.p-panel-no-padding-bottom .p-panel-content {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

2. or in the app component css

```css
:host /deep/ .p-panel-no-padding-bottom .p-panel-content {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
```